# How to run AsyncTask in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I previously wrote a simple currency converter program, that fetches real time rate conversion via an exchange rate API. The full code is available here: https://github.com/LaChope/expenses-robot

I want know to reuse most of this code to build an Android app, but I am really not familiar with AsyncTask and do know how to implement it (I need it for the GET requests).

Here is what I've implemented so far, but I am not sure it is the correct way to proceed.

My Converter class:

```
public class Converter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Float> {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private final EditText baseCurrency;
    private final EditText targetCurrency;
    private final EditText amount;

    public Converter(EditText baseCurrency, EditText targetCurrency, EditText amount) {
        this.baseCurrency = baseCurrency;
        this.targetCurrency = targetCurrency;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Override
    protected Float doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?" + baseCurrency;
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root = null;
        try {
            root = mapper.readTree(responseEntity.getBody());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String rates1 = "rates";
        JsonNode name = root.get(rates1);
        JsonNode rates = name.get(String.valueOf(targetCurrency));
        float rate = rates.floatValue();

        return rate;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Float rate) {
        super.onPostExecute(rate);
        output.setText();
        return;
    }
}
```

My MainActivity class:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void displayResult(View view) {
        EditText textBaseCurrency = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.base_currency);
        EditText textTargetCurrency = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target_currency);
        EditText textAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
        TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        output.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

        Converter converter = new Converter(textBaseCurrency, textTargetCurrency, textAmount);
        output.setText();
    }
}
```

How to communicate the output of my conversion made in the Converter class to the MainActivity to display it?

Comment: `converter.execute();` is missing. And in onPostExecute you can display result and that is what you nearly do. output.setText(result);

Answer (score 0):

Initialize AsyncTask as

```
Converter converter = new Converter(textBaseCurrency, textTargetCurrency, textAmount);    
converter.execute();
```

Then the code in AsyncTask will start executing.

Assign `output.setText();` in `onPostExecute(Float rate) {}`.

Comment: The issue is that `output.setText();` needs `TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
output.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);` and I cannot put that in the `Converter.java` class, right?